# PouchDB <input type="file" multiple /> - can this work? How?

Tags: pouchdb

I've got a webapp/Cordova app that has a basic form to fill out and then sync the data to CouchDB. Everything works, except I can't get PouchDB to accept multiple file (image) attachments provided by the user from the form. I've read and tried to use the examples from the PouchDB documentation on putAttachment, but can't find any examples that clarify how to use putAttachement to put user input attachments from something like:

```
<input type="file" id="attachment" name="attachment" multiple />
```

I've not been able to figure out how to grab all images input and send the (putAttachment) through PouchDB to CouchdB. Working Plnkr is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/fKxazltC6WftptKEAR5T?p=info

```
local.put(mileageDoc, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < storedFiles.length; i++) {
      local.putAttachment(response.id, storedFiles[i].name, response.rev, storedFiles[i], storedFiles[i].type, function(err, response){
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Document created Successfully");
          console.log("response id:" + response.id);
          console.log("response id:" + response.rev);
          console.log("storedFiles length:" + storedFiles.length);
        }
      });
    }
    clearFields();
  }
});
```

It was suggested to use recursion but I'm really struggling to figure out how to make that work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Got it. The 'edit' notes said 37 characters were changed so I thought there was some small code fix. ;).

Comment: good point... not sure why it says that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use blob library and make a loop to put the images one a time.

Comment: After reading the docs and reviewing example code I'm confused. The 12 pro tips for better code with PouchDB article (https://pouchdb.com/2014/06/17/12-pro-tips-for-better-code-with-pouchdb.html) number 6 says:  "Don't just update docs for the hell of it. Every time you modify a document, another revision is added to its revision history – think Git. Except unlike Git, these revisions contain the full document data (not just the diffs), which can take up a lot of space on disk. So if nothing changed in a document, don't bother put()ing it again." A loop will force a put() for each loop.

Comment: I made some progress in that I have a loop and the first of the multiple files loads. But I apparently haven't coded correctly to pull the current _rev at the end of each pass through the loop so only the first attachment goes through. I have it up on Plnkr here: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/fKxazltC6WftptKEAR5T?p=info)

It's been suggested to use recursion instead of a loop - but I've not idea how.

I'll post the solution when found as I'm sure others will at some point want to use `<input type='file' multiple>`